DeletionPolicy property is not permitted for AWS::RDS::DBInstance?
When I create an AWS CloudFormation resource of type AWS::RDS::DBInstance and specify DeletionPolicy: Delete in the template, I get the following error in the CloudFormation Stacks console:

Properties validation failed for resource MysqlInstance with message: [#: extraneous key [DeletionPolicy] is not permitted]

In the template, I did not use the DBClusterIdentifier property.
According to this reference, the DeletionPolicy will default to Snapshot if no DBClusterIdenfier property is specified. It does not mention, however, that it is illegal to use the DeletionPolicy property if the DBClusterIdentifier property is not used. So, I'm confused why I am getting this error?

What is your actual template with AWS::RDS::DBInstance?

hi @marcin, i figured out the error. I placed DeletionPolicy under AWS::RDS::DBInstance->Properties in the template. DeletionPolicy should not be under Properties but should be directly under AWS::RDS::DBInstance. Thank you.

Template should have been written this way:
Resources:
  MyDB:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      ...

instead of:
Resources:
  MyDB:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      DeletionPolicy: Delete
      ...

